# How to Redirect any subdomain request to main domain in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect all subdomain requests for domain.com to www.domain.com and user must access all part of website only by enter to main domain and click on links , for example if user directly enter following address in browser:

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

OR

```
www.domain.com/post/showPost.aspx?pid=11
```

i want to show error page and then redirect to www.domain.com

i use asp.net and IIS 7.5 and visual studio 2010

Thank you.

Comment: A quick [google search](http://bit.ly/NHOUI6) returned a [seemingly pertinent article](http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/blog/8/IIS-7-URL-Rewrite-subdomains-and-host-headers).  Is there something additional you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes i try it.but cannot find any thing....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the URL Rewriting module could be the way to go. Try using configuration similar to the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This will redirect without showing an error page. If you want to show an error page then you'll need to redirect to a page that takes the return URL and does a client-side redirect to the right place.

As @inspile says you're going to have trouble doing it for sub-pages of the site. You may be able to do it using the referer to make sure it's from a link on the main site. Again the URL Rewrite module is the way to go here.

Cheers

Comment: yes ... i place it in configuration...but when i run website and try s1.localhost.com , browser show me "server not found " error

Comment: why you dont use <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" /> instead of <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" /> ???

Answer (score 0):

For the subdomains, you can either redirect them using your web hosting's Control Panel, or if you have the subdomains setup on a server that you can remote into, use the URL Rewrite module in IIS Manager to redirect all requests for the subdomain to your www subdomain. Using URL Rewrite, you don't have to show an error page, the redirect will happen automatically.

You're not going to be able to restrict users from accessing pages using links only.

Comment: Add the code from the other answer to each subdomain's web.config and you'll be good to go for the subdomains.