# Redirect www sub-domain to main domain with the same path using IIS Rewrite

Tags: c#, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I'm using IIS rewrite rule from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552321/8388835

but redirect is not working when it contains a page, for ex.: www.example.com/somepage should be redirected to https://example.com/somepage, it works only with root path (www.example.com -> https://example.com). How to make it working with any specified page? 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420094/how-to-redirect-any-subdomain-request-to-main-domain-in-asp-net

Comment: sorry, but it's working the same way as solution I'm using now...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. I found the answer in this question: [http to https redirect - iis8.5 url rewrite 2.0 redirect rule not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597356/http-to-https-redirect-iis8-5-url-rewrite-2-0-redirect-rule-not-working)

The issue was because I also had another IIS rewrite rule, I changed it's order and all is working fine now.